# Firestore partial sync

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app with multiple users where each one will need to access only theirs data. Also all data should de accessible by an admin user. How can I make to Firestore only sync the collections that a user can read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firestore SDK will only locally cache the documents that the client actually reads.  There is no operation for "cache everything I can read".  You will have to write code to read the documents that you would like stored in local cache.